# Angular preview page with difftool

Tags: angularjs, preview, user-experience

have a web page that allows a user user to preview the changes they made.

The page has a grid with data and the user can edit each row. In the preview, the user wants to see what he/she has changed.

Something like this grid http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php

So I need to implement some kind of preview that show the differences. For example underlining deleted content with red, or new content with green etc.

I've searched the web for this problem but I didn't manage to find anything on the best practice about it.

Where can I read about user experience best practices related to creating a preview page with the ability to emphasize changes that were made by the user (where the user will be able to check what things they've changed, deleted or added)?

Comment: It depends on the complexity of the page that user can edit... Can you provide an example? Your question is too generic even to attempt to answer

Comment: if it's not about the coding howto/bug/problem, then maybe http://ux.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place or the question?

Comment: Thank you for the point. I updated question. Actually it's page with grid on it and user has possibility to edit each row and each column.

Comment: 2 shershen yeah i think it make sence to post this question there. Thank you